# What should I use to move flex items through main axis?

Tags: css, flexbox

In flexbox there's a align-self property which lets to move a flex item  through cross axis. I heard there isn't a justify-self property . So is there any way to make it flex-start/center/flex-end  on main axis for a flex item?

Comment: You can do some more learning on the container/items on flex. The guide from css-tricks seems to be good for you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It's good to consider the related question you get when writing yours ... the second one was the one you need

Answer (score 0):

Use margins.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.child:last-of-type {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can use the default behaviour of margin-left / right to influence individual items.